# Disable scrolling with draggable div

Tags: jquery, scroll, draggable

I have a div which is draggable. When I drag it close to one of the edges on the webpage the whole website scroll. Can I disable this function? 
(I can basically use the div to move around the webpage, but I want it to be limited to where I'm currently at)
I use the jquery draggable script!

The header:

```
link href="stilmallaudioplayer.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#audioplayer" ).draggable();
});
</script>
```

The body:

```
<div id="audioplayer" class="ui-widget-content">
<audio controls class="ui-widget-content">
<source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</div>
```

Note: this is not my full code, just the draggable div part!

The css:

```
#audioplayer { 
    padding: 0.5em; 
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `overflow:hidden` on the `body` or the container element on drag `start` and remove it on drag `stop` :

Js:

```
$("#audioplayer").draggable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $('body').addClass("overflow");
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $('body').removeClass("overflow");
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
overflow{overflow:hidden;} //Use inline style or  !important if other css overrides this
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guynyepe/2/)

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $("#audioplayer").draggable(
    { containment: "html", scroll: false }

    );
});
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

    #audioplayer {
        padding: 0.5em;
        z-index: 3;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height:20px;
        width: 100px;
    }
```